# How to calculate total amount of childs and show in parent using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my result set

```
id  Parent      text        type        Cr

1   0       Parent1     Default     0.00
2   1       parent1.1   Default     0.00
3   1       parent1.2   Default     0.00
4   2       Child1      Master      10.00
5   2       child2      Master      20.00
6   3       child1      Master      25.00
7   3       child2      Master      50.00
```

i have follwing dataset, i want to calculate total amount  of childs want to show in parent  and all sub parent totals in main parent

tree structure is like this

```
                               Total Cr 
Parent1---------------------------105
    parent1.1---------------------30
        Child1------------10
        child2------------20
    parent1.2---------------------75
        child1------------25
        child2------------50
```

i have tried follwing

```
for (i = 0; i < $scope.treeData.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.treeData[i].type == 'default') {

        var ICr = 0.00;
        angular.forEach(data.Table, function (items456) {

            var Itm123Cr = eval(items456.Cr);

            IDr += parseFloat(Itm123Cr == undefined ? 0 : Itm123Cr),

            $scope.treeData[i] = {
                "id": $scope.treeData[i].id, "parent": $scope.treeData[i].parent, "text": $scope.treeData[i].text,
                "data": {

                    "Cr": ICr
                },
                "type": $scope.treeData[i].type,
            }

            });

    }
}
```

so i want to filter dataset like (Master type only contains data)

```
id  Parent      text        type        Cr

1   0       Parent1     Default     105.00
2   1       parent1.1   Default     30.00
3   1       parent1.2   Default     75.00
4   2       Child1      Master      10.00
5   2       child2      Master      20.00
6   3       child1      Master      25.00
7   3       child2      Master      50.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the other answer.. That was not correct. I Misunderstood the question

Take a look at the following:

```
var data = [
{id: 1, parent: null, type: 'default', text: 'root', cr: 0},
{id: 2, parent: 1, type: 'default', text: 'Parent 1', cr: 0},
{id: 3, parent: 1, type: 'default', text: 'Parent 2', cr: 0},
{id: 4, parent: 2, type: 'master', text: 'Child 1 P1', cr: 10},
{id: 5, parent: 2, type: 'master', text: 'Child 2 P1', cr: 20},
{id: 6, parent: 3, type: 'master', text: 'Child 1 P2', cr: 25},
{id: 7, parent: 3, type: 'master', text: 'Child 2 P2', cr: 50}
];


function run() {


data.forEach(function (item, index, arr) {
    if (item.parent != null) {
        //something like:
        var indexOfParent = findParent(item.parent);
        if (indexOfParent === -1) {
            //ERROR! no parent found!
            console.warn('No parent found!');
        }
        else {
            var parent = data[indexOfParent];//0based
            if (!parent.children) {
                parent.children = [];
            }
            parent.children.push(item);
        }
    }
});

//new function
function findParent(parentId){
    var index;
    index = data.findIndex(function(element){
       return element.id == parentId;
    });
    return index
}

function normalize(parent) {
    if (parent.parent != null) {
        if (parent && parent.children) {
            for (var i = 0, l = parent.children.length; i < l; ++i) {
                var child = parent.children[i];
                parent.cr += child.cr;
                //child.index = i;
                //if (!child.parentId) child.parentId = parent.id || '0';
                normalize(child);
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log(parent.cr);
        }
    }
}

data.forEach(function (a) {
    normalize(a)
})
//UPDATE 2
var rootIndex = data.findIndex(function(element){
    return element.parent == null;
})

var root = data[rootIndex];
root.children.forEach(function(child){
    root.cr+=child.cr;
})
//normalize(data);
}

run();
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Jordy,i given sample data in previous ,am getting problem with my original data i have added code (updated my question) .. am getting problem here  var parent = data[item.parent - 1];  (i don't have parent id in sequence)i have tried changing of code but getting issue as maximum call stock exceeded(error in browser console)

Comment: @sumangoud, I updated the answer with a findParent function. also take a look at the following site https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods as reference

Comment: If this is the right answer please mark it as answer

Comment: how to remove children after from array after calculating .. i have tried this but not working    for (var k = data.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
                      var children = data[0].children;
                      if (children != undefined) {
                          data.children.splice(k, 1);
                      }

Comment: am strucked there Jordy, remaining  calculation working

Comment: i removed children after calculation,but getting issue at calculation, 1st parent childs calculating correctly but in second parent (value calculating 3 times )

Comment: You can calculate the root seperately after processing the others.. loop over the root's children and += the children cr

Comment: can you please help me am not getting

Comment: main parent calculating correct but getting issue at child parent calculation i have updated my question (child parent calculation issue)

Comment: Instead of posting every problem you are racing here, try to debug the answer i gave you and see whats happening. SO is not here to solve all your issues.. if you have Fins the bug and cannot fix it yourself. Post a nee question

Comment: Thank you Jordy, i have lot of confusion there that's why i posted every time .now it is working

Comment: upto to level 3 , main parent, parent sub parent values caclulating correctly
but if level 3 has sub prents and childs (inside parent and child valus calculating correctly),but levall 3 parent value not taking level 2 parent.

Comment: can you please suggest what to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150262/discussion-between-suman-goud-and-jordy-van-eijk).